# How can I find the API level of a project I opened in Android Studio?

Tags: android, api

I'm new to Android Studio.
My SDK package includes a range of API's.

I received a half-completed project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is located in the `build.gradle` where you go to the project section by click **ALT+1** twice or click **1:project** tab in the left corner

and go to Gradle Scripts section and click `build.gradle` and check the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` version of the project

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.otd.octranspodestination"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: I'm opening a google sample project and encountered gradle complaint. but the build.gradle file has no `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` at all. Studio version 3.1.4